# AWS Glue with RDS SQL Server

Tags: pyspark, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I have created an AWS Glue Job (pyspark script), which pulls the data from S3 bucket and load the data into RDS (SQL Server). I have to perform few pre-actions (delete selective data) on the destination table before loading the data. For this, i have used data-frames i.e. bring the entire destination table data into data frame first then performing the delete operation and finally appending (UNION) the data with source data (S3) and loading into RDS table.

Looks like this is not a feasible approach, as it has to load entire destination table data into memory first for performing pre-action. Also there are two connections gets established within the script (JDBC and Glue context), what if one commit gets executed successfully but the other gets failed.

Can someone please suggest the better approach for performing these operations along with maintaining proper TRANSACTION properties?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the transformation logic used for loading data into RDS?

Comment: Hi Prabhakar, There is no such Transformation Logic applied. The issue is with the selective delete process. Like with Redshift, we have an option of using queries in "preaction" & "postaction" for performing task before or after data load operation. I am looking for similar type of option for RDS SQL SERVER. I have to perform some delete operation on the destination rds table for some set of data before loading the new data into RDS table. But for performing this operation, i have to load entire data into data frame first. Looking for some alternate approach